# "IS NOT NULL" Is still showing NULL SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm using Microsoft's SQL server to write a query to display information about the customer that placed the order with Id equal to 10643 using LEFT JOIN.
This is a query I wrote:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders 
ON OrderID = 10835
AND Orders.OrderID IS NOT NULL
AND Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
```

The result I'm getting includes Orders.OrderID as NULL
[image: The result]

While The result I want is this:
[image: This]

I would like to know why even when I select NOT NULL for the OrderID of Orders for the matching condition, The result still shows NULL.
Thanks y'all in advance

Comment: You're using a `LEFT JOIN`, which means you're prepared to handle the case where no order exists. If you don't want that, use an `INNER JOIN`. You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and then filter out the `NULL` rows in a `WHERE` (rather than the `ON`) but then you're just using the same semantics as an `INNER JOIN` and you may as well use that.

Comment: *inner joins* return only rows that match on both sides of the join; *outer* joins return *all rows* from the left (or right) side of the join. I would suggest reading some [join tutorials](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-joins-made-easy/) / [where tutorials](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/05/where-clause-in-sql/#:~:text=Where%20clause%20is%20used%20to,clause%20of%20the%20SQL%20query.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to LEFT JOIN on just the CustomerID then filter in a WHERE clause, eg

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers 
LEFT JOIN Orders 
ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
WHERE Orders.OrderID = 10835
```

There's no need for IS NOT NULL, since you're filtering all those out already.  Note that since you're filtering on the outer table, the query is now equivalent to an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers 
JOIN Orders 
ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
WHERE Orders.OrderID = 10835
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I was just messing around and trying different ways to do the same task on a problem. I always learn new things by doing this. By the way, The mistake I made here is not joining with CustomerID and filtering with WHERE.